# xls file getting stored as folder on uploading to server

Tags: php, excel, laravel-5.4

I am using laravel 5.4 and trying to upload some bank statements which are in xls format, to the server.

File is getting uploaded on the disk, but instead of creating an excel file a directory with a .txt file inside it is creating.

This txt file contains the contents of xls file.

```
.
├── 835e9d46-b43d-11e7-ad3c-847beb400c7ebank-statement.xls
│   └── 0qaYUFrYBLfDupI5v1GlUBuU6aVA8ZQTKdCrR90o.txt
└── bd4cb0fa-b43e-11e7-bdc8-847beb400c7ebank-statement.xls
    └── 2h2Z5Fy6seJtxxxAsYitZwTfA48XIOIpnc7W58xP.txt
```

view file code

```
{{ Form::open(['route' => 'upload-statement', 'class' => 'form-horizontal', 'files' => true]) }}
                            {{ csrf_field() }}



                            <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('statement_file') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                                <label for="email" class="col-md-4 control-label">Chose statement file</label>

                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <input autocomplete="off" id="statement_file" type="file" class="form-control" name="statement_file"  required autofocus >

                                    @if ($errors->has('statement_file'))
                                        <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('statement_file') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                    @endif
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('ga_code') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                                <label for="password" class="col-md-4 control-label">GA Code</label>

                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <input id="ga_code" type="text" class="form-control" name="ga_code" required>

                                    @if ($errors->has('ga_code'))
                                        <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('ga_code') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                    @endif
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="control-label col-lg-4"></label>
                                <div class="col-lg-8">
                                    <button class="btn btn-primary" id="uploadbankfileid" name="uploadbankfileid">Upload File</button>                                        </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
```

controller code

```
$statementFile = request()->file('statement_file');


$newFileName = Uuid::uuid1() . "bank-statement." . $statementFile->getClientOriginalExtension();

$originalFileName = $statementFile->getClientOriginalName();


$path = $request->file('statement_file')->store(
            '/'.$newFileName, 'bank-statements',['mimeType'=>$statementFile->getClientMimeType(),'mime'=>$statementFile->getClientOriginalExtension()]
        );
```

Comment: How you upload the file and how create you it?

Comment: try it with guessClientExtension instead of getClientOriginalExtension

Comment: done but not working

Comment: replace this $request->file('statement_file') in  $statementFile and store function has only 2 parameters you have 3

Comment: What is your point I am not getting, and store function has 3 params last one is optional array of options see here https://laravel.com/api/5.4/Illuminate/Http/UploadedFile.html#method_store

Comment: my fault i have looked at a wrong version

Answer (score 0):

in the doku it stands:

"The store method accepts the path where the file should be stored relative to the filesystem's configured root directory. This path should not contain a file name, since a unique ID will automatically be generated to serve as the file name."

the first parameter are only the folder where it should saved

use storeAs function

```
 storeAs(string $path, string $name, array|string $options = [])
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what solved my problem

```
$statementFile = request()->file('statement_file');
$newFileName = Uuid::uuid1() . "-bank-statement." . $statementFile->getClientOriginalExtension();
$uplodedPath = $statementFile->storeAs("/", $newFileName, ['disk' => 'bank-statements']);
```

UploadedFile::store() method takes just two arguments first argument is the name of the directory in which file is intended to be stored, and second argument String disk-name or if array the ['disk'=>'disk-name'] of the folder. store method can be used for cases where we dont need any custom naming convention for the files uploaded.

UploadedFile::storeAs() takes three arguments, second argument is the custom name for the file generated, first and third arguments are same as first and second argument of UploadedFies::store() method.